# Where is eclipse.exe?

Tags: eclipse

I just donwloaded and unzipped the latest Android sdk, but cannot find eclipse.exe in any of the folders.

Should it be there, or am I looking for the wrong thing?

Cheers guys.

Comment: I take it your OS doesn't have a search function.

Comment: That was the first thing I did before posting here - searched the OS. No Eclipse. I wouldn't have posted here without eliminating some basic options first.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is you can download them separately

Eclipse is an IDE (Integrated development environment) and we use Android SDK as plugin to it.

[Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) is now a part of Android SDK.

thanks Shaun for bringing it in notice

Comment: Hi Rakesh. Are you sure? The Android download contains both and eclipse dir, and an sdk one. Plus, the instructions at Android say to launch eclipse from the same dir that the sdk came in - http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

Comment: Hi Shaun Thanks .. its my mistake because 1 year before when i was working on android platform we were used to download Android SDK and eclipse separately And after plugin that to eclipse is tedious task. 
its nice that google came up with pre plugedin sdk.
why dont you search for Eclipse folder as your link mentioned?
..
if it doesnt work then go for separate installation :-)

Comment: Yeah _ I'll try a separate insatllation. I think maybe they're written the wrong instructions with the release. Cheers mate.